# I've forgotten the name of the team(s) I'm being considered for -- will asking the recruiter reflect poorly on me?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process, united-states

So this is somewhat embarrassing...

I'm most of the way through a job application with "Company A" -- I've had phone screenings, on-sites, and then one final meet-and-greet with a bunch of hiring managers whose teams I would potentially be joining. So far so good and it looks like they may make me an offer. I met with the hiring managers and they mentioned their team names at the start of the conversation, and then we chatted for an hour or so on a huge number of topics.

Lo and behold, after a weekend, the names of the particular teams "Company A" had me meet with have slipped my mind. I'm very excited about the work the teams are doing, it's not a situation where I don't care / am uninterested, I just had a brain fart and forgot.

The recruiter is following up with me and wants to know if I'm leaning towards any particular team, but I'm blanking on what to say back since I don't remember the team names and I'm worried it will reflect poorly on me if I ask, and might impact my salary negotiations.

Is there a tactful way to recover from this? I've tried googling the people I met with (ironically I remember all their names) but they do not list their specific teams on their online profiles and there is no public company directory. I **am** leaning towards one particular team, however the manager I met with who covers that team covers other teams as well, so simply saying "John Doe's Team" isn't specific enough to answer the question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I will update the OP but yes -- I am leaning towards one team, but one of the managers I met with oversees multiple teams, so just saying "Jim Doe's Team" is unfortunately not specific enough!

Comment: Do these teams have specific, chosen names? Or are they just named after the thing they work on?

Comment: @Erik they have names related to the work they do, but business-speak-y and I'm not terribly familiar (coming from small startup). things like User Intake, Growth and Retention, Internal Systems Architecture, etc.. The role for all 3 is the same (frontend development) but the team names / semantics are slightly different.

Comment: I second what @JoeStrazzere said. If you could somehow put things mentioned in the conversation that drew you to that team, it will come off less as you didn't pay attention and more as, "wow he was overloaded with information."

Comment: Hi new user.   Surely you know/remember **what they worked on** ....??  Simply state it that way.  "Yes, I'm interested in the Javascript team."  Simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a tactful way to recover from this?

I don't see how asking for the names of the teams could harm your application in any way if you do it professionally.

You may not know the *names* of the teams, but you know the *names of the teammates* and also *what sort of projects they do*. In case you do have a preference in your mind already, perhaps try replying this:

> Hello Mr. Recruiter. I liked very much meeting with you last time, it helped me get a good idea of what you guys do.
>
> As of now, I think that I feel particular interest in the team (whose name I happen to forget) where they are working on [X], the one where Mr. Cygnus is on. If there is anything else you may need feel free to reach out.

Answer (score 3):

In my dealings with recruiters they have gone out of their way to hide any faux pas on my side. They are at least as eager to get you into the position as you are.

Besides, any reasonable person would understand that you might be juggling multiple job applications at once, at the same time as working your current day-to-day job.

Answer (score -1):

Is there some way you could ask for "more details" about the goals and problems the team is facing? During an elaboration like that it should readily give away the functions of the team.